# Finding Pygame and Python 3.2

Tags: python, pygame

I'm completely new to programming and am trying to get my feet wet.  I've been using the absolutely lovely "Python Programming for the Absolute Beginner" by Michael Dawson.  The problem is that in the later chapters he wants the reader to use pygame (actually a version he apparently modified himself, but close enough).  The problem is that I'm having trouble finding it and installing for Python 3.2

Is there an extremely simple and easy way to download and use it?  All that I can find is pygame for 2.x and the some shadowy explanations for creating it myself or using terminal magic, both of which elude me with my experience level.  Is there some straightforward way, or do I have to bumble in the dark using those seemingly convoluted directions?  Thanks guys

EDIT:  OK guys, you are all still lovely, but I need Pygame for Mac.  I am feeling incredibly frustrated since I don't want to need Windows!

Comment: I see pygame for the 3.2 on thier site http://pygame.org/ftp/pygame-1.9.2a0.win32-py3.2.msi  @ http://www.pygame.org/download.shtml

Comment: Link to the specific page in the book (if available) so we can help you with getting his modified library

Comment: Anything for the Mac OS? Should I just run windows 7 and bootcamp?  I'd love to not have to do this since I don't have windows 7 atm.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

This site has an unoffical pygame library that has been updated for python 3.2. 
Search the page for:

pygame-1.9.2pre.win-amd64-py3.2.‌exe
or
pygame-1.9.2pre.win32-py3.2.‌exe

There are several options.